# how to upload images to database?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, multer

I am trying to upload images to database.I am using express nodejs sequelize ,I am also using multer.Some images are stored in db while some not.can anyone help me with this?
//this is my code which i am using to store images in db.

```
const fs = require("fs");

const db = require("../models");
const Image = db.images;

const uploadFiles = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.file);

    if (req.file == undefined) {
      return res.send(`You must select a file.`);
    }

    Image.create({
      type: req.file.mimetype,
      name: req.file.originalname,
      data: fs.readFileSync(
        __basedir + "/resources/static/assets/uploads/" + req.file.filename
      ),
    }).then((image) => {
      fs.writeFileSync(
        __basedir + "/resources/static/assets/tmp/" + image.name,
        image.data
      );

      return res.send(`File has been uploaded.`);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.send(`Error when trying upload images: ${error}`);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  uploadFiles,
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You may consider providing some additional information, as your question may be hard to answer with only the provided information. For example: What type of database are you using? What error message are you receiving? What have already tried doing to resolve the problem?

Comment: I am using Mysql to store the images. Its like I can store images upto 1 MB. Cant store more than that. Doesn't show any error as well..it will just load